# How to add markers on Google Map from a Database Arraylist

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, arraylist

I don't get how to add Markers on GoogleMaps from an Arraylist out of a Database.

I already tried a lot but nothing worked.

Array List from Database:

```java
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetUserByUserId(int userid){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT Loc, Lat, Long FROM "+ TABLE_Users;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Users, new String[]{LocationName, Latitude, Longitude}, KEY_ID+ "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(userid)},null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("Loc",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationName)));
        user.put("Lat",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Latitude)));
        user.put("Long",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Longitude)));
        userList.add(user);
    }
    return  userList;
}
```

My attempt

```java
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Database db = new Database(this);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = db.GetUsers();
    mMap = googleMap;
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(userList.get(i).get("latitude").toString());
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(userList.get(i).get("longitude").toString());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
    }
```

Google Maps should show all Markers from the Latitude and Longitude from the Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `userList` list contains your locations in this format when you print it out:

```
Log.d("userListTag", userList.toString())
```

Output:

```
userListTag: [{Loc=California, Long=-117.985904, Lat=35.125801}, {Loc=Las Vegas, Long=-115.13983, Lat=36.169941}]
```

When I run your code, I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object
>   reference

This is because you are attempting to get "latitude" and "longitude" which don't exist as keys in `userList`. Try replacing them with "Lat" and "Long" instead, like this:

```
latitude = Double.parseDouble(userList.get(i).get("Lat").toString());
longitude = Double.parseDouble(userList.get(i).get("Long").toString());
```

I tested your code with the above changes on my end and both sample markers showed up fine on my map, so I hope this helps you!

Comment: Glad to hear and happy to have been of help! :)